# jQuery effects: when modal box opens and when it closes

Tags: jquery

I have finally ended fixing a problem I had with AJAX and jQuery modal box.

Now I just want to add the tipical effects... but I don't know the code.

**effect one:** when the modal box opens, I want the "background" to fade

**effect two:** when you hit the X to close the box, I want it to fade slowly

Look:

```
<script src="js/simplemodal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#message-sent').hide();
        $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $("#message-sent").modal({
                        onOpen: function(dialog) {
                            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                                dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                                    dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
                                });
                            });
                        },
                        onClose: function (dialog) {
                            dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                                dialog.container.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                                        $.modal.close();
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        },
                        closeClass: 'close-btn'
                    });
                }
            });
            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at would be to use the options built into SimpleModal to achieve what you need.

This section of code:

```
success: function() {
    $("#message-sent").fadeIn().modal({
         closeClass: 'close-btn'
    });
}
```

should be modified to use the built-in structure provided by SimpleModal to launch the modal box. The `dialog.overlay.fadeIn()` is what you're looking at to make the background fade:

```
success: function() {
    $("#message-sent").modal({
        onOpen: function(dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

As for closing the modal box, you can call `$.modal.close();` to close the modal box, or assign a `simplemodal-close` class to any element that you wish to allow the modal box to close upon clicking. SimpleModal wil automatically bind the close action to them.

You can also add animations to the close, using the following:

```
onClose: function (dialog) {
    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Great. I edited the code. Your only missing the "darkening of the back" (I don't know how to extress it). However I gave you the answer since you did 75% of the question ;) But try to help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'm not sure what you mean by "darkening of the back". I assume you're trying to edit the color of the overlay? If so, try the following CSS: `.simplemodal-overlay { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); }`

Comment: AWESOME ;) THAT's WHAT I MEANT. THANKS